# Is it safe to assume that when bootin a desktop computer from a flash drive no residual files stay on the computer's RAM and hard drives?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, memory, security

Does booting (not installing) a desktop computer from a flash drive simulate an airgapped environment so as to perform highly-sensitive operations, assuming that the desktop computer doesn't have a network adapter installed and the objective is that no info is left on the computer's RAM or hard drives? What is the most effective way to flush the RAM in this case?

Comment: No, you are making a faulty assumption.  The method of booting does not imply any capabilities of (nor impose restrictions on) the software that is loaded & executed.  I could provide to you a bootable flash drive that would wipe out all of your storage drives.

Comment: The most effective way to flush the RAM is to turn off the computer.

Comment: @sawdust thanks so if I were to remove any hard drives from the computer and then load Ubuntu for example from a USB flash drive then this issue is solved, no?

Comment: @harrymc I was under the impression that while the computer is plugged in the state of the RAM is preserved, isn't this the case?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. While all RAM content will be erased when you turn off the computer, there is no guarantee that your hard drive will not be touched. There are lots off bootable usb tools made to manipulate and change hard drive archives and properties.
If attached, the hard drive is as accesible from a flash drive that it is from an operating system installed in it.
The system you're running in it (ex. TAILS) is more important that the method used (booting from a flash drive).

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to flush the RAM is to turn off the computer.

Truly turning off the computer, not using Sleep or Hibernation, will erase memory.
Even if the computer is still connected to the mains, power is not used for the RAM.

If Wake-on-LAN is enabled, some minimal power will be used for keeping the
network adapter and BIOS, but only functional enough to wake up the computer
if the wake package arrives.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way you use the Bootable Flash Drive. If you use it to mount or access some files on your Hard Disk, then it can / will leave residuals.

If you are using, for example, Arch Linux or another Distro which doesn't automatically mount Hard Drives or access it in any way (Applications, Scripts, etc...) then you can be safe that nothing is on the Hard Disk.

The RAM on the other hand is pretty easy to erase. Just shut down the computer. To be absolutely safe that nothing stays on the RAM you can disconnect the pc from the power line and push the on/off button a few times.